# Representation of a rational number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

the euclidean algorithm of division can represent an element of $\mathbb{Q} $ by decimal expansion, I know this euclidean algorithm can't generate a period of 9. Well, what is an example of an algorithm to represent a rational number by it decimal expansion and it can't generated a period of zeroes? For exemple 0.2 cannot be obtained but I can obtain 0.19999...

Comment: by "decimal svilup", do you mean decimal expansion?

Comment: Is this a translation to English?  I might guess that "rappresentation" was supposed to be "representation" but I have no idea what "svilup" is.

Comment: And what do you mean by "... can't generate a period of 9" ?

Comment: Yes, I mean decimal expansion and representation

Comment: This is not clear.  If your decimal terminates, replace the $0's$ with $9's$, and lower the penultimate digit by $1$.  What more of an algorithm do you need?

Comment: @Matti for example the euclidean algorithm can't generate 1,23999999999...

Comment: @lulu in my textbook the author sais euclidean algorithm can't generate a period of 9, but yes exist for example an algorithm to representing a rational number whit no period of 0.

Comment: @user yes this is a translation from Italian to english

Comment: The division algorithm gives the terminating expansion. We have $0.9999\cdots =1$, but we can easily avoid the breakdown of the uniqueness, if we do not allow this period. This period is something like a "degenerated" case, as a line instead of a triangle. Period $0000\cdots$ also is equivalent to termination. Hence this period also has to be ruled out. A period like $0.623623\cdots$ can be represented with $\frac{623}{999}$ which is already in the lowest terms not giving an integer, the special periods would give $\frac 09$ or $\frac 99$ which both are integers.